# error '1004 Unable to set the formulaarray property of range class

Tags: vba, excel

Before this may be deleted as a duplicate post, I have read all of the other posts and tried the solutions.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, b + 5).Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=IF(AND(AY2=""Yes"",BF2=""Unsure""),TEXTJOIN(""|"", TRUE, IF(BE2=Data!H:H, Data!I:I, TEXT("",""))),""N/A""))"
```

I have also tried (removed "" from TEXT("",""):

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, b + 5).Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=IF(AND(AY2=""Yes"",BF2=""Unsure""),TEXTJOIN(""|"", TRUE, IF(BE2=Data!H:H, Data!I:I, TEXT(,))),""N/A""))"
```

I have manually used this formula in Excel and it works. The formula is far less than 255 characaters, so I am thinking its a syntax/formula error? Not sure because it works in Excel.

Comment: Your uses of `TEXT("","")` and `TEXT(,)` do not look right. `TEXT` needs 2 args: a number and a format code. If you want to insert a comma, then try `"",""`. If you want to format `Data!I:I`, then try `TEXT(Data!I:I,format_code)`. If you want to insert an empty string, try `""""`.

Comment: If you have manually used the formula in Excel itself and it works as you say, then run this in the immediate window with the cell where the formula lives selected `? Selection.FormulaArray`. That will print the formula in proper VBA syntax which you can copy / paste into the VBE.

Comment: @xidgel `TEXT(,)` return an empty string.  there are those on this site that prefer it to `""` in their formulas.

Comment: you have one too many `)` on the end of your formula.

Comment: As @ScottCraner pointed out, I had one too many ) at the end of the formula. Silly mistake. FYI, you can remove the """" around the TEXT("","") and it will work. So I used TEXT(,)  Thanks everyone!